# calculating arithmetic progression with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to make a function that is given the first number in an arithmetic progression, the derivation d and the number of terms in the series which is n and then calculate their sum using recursion
I tried the following

```
def rec_sum(a_1, d, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    return (n*(a_1+rec_sum(a_1,d,n-1)))/2

print rec_sum(2,2,4)
```

which gives me 18 instead of 20
thanks for the help

Comment: There's clearly something wrong with your code, since you do not use the value d - like, at all. You just pass it down the next recursive step without doing anything with it. I am not sure what you mean by "derivation" - I thought it is a function that has something to do with differential algebra. But clearly this is not the case here. Then again - English is not my first language.

Comment: "which gives me 18 instead of 20 thanks for the help" - debug your code and come back with your findings. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
def rec_sum(a_1, d, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    return a_1 + rec_sum(a_1 + d, d, n-1)

print rec_sum(2, 2, 4)
```

**output:**

```
20
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler way to find the sum of arithmetic progression, but if you need the recursion -

```
def rec_sum(first_element, step, seq_length):
    if seq_length <= 0:
        return 0
    return first_element + rec_sum(first_element + step, step, seq_length - 1)
```